# how to get number of documents which is created today with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how to get number of documents which is created today with mongoose? I'm using MEAN stack. I read [Mongoose Api Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) but doesn't understand anything :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default there is no way.

Documents don't have creation date associated with them unless you explicitly store it in MongoDB.

In other words your Mongoose schema should have something like `created` field:

```
const blogSchema = new Schema({
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Then search for matching docs:

```
const now = new Date();
const today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
doc.find({created: {$gte: today}}).exec(callback);
```

Comment: yes I have this field and how do I get number of users which registered today?

Comment: `doc.find({created: {$gte: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate())}}).exec(...)` 

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: this is in my profile. info > createDate: 2016-01-04T14:06:29.617Z

Comment: var now = new Date();

Comment: `const` and `let` are new keywords in ES6 / ECMAScript2015, which you should start using instead of `var`.  They are supported by the latest Node.js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: `Documents don't have creation date associated with them unless you explicitly store it in MongoDB` --> Wrong, there is a retrievable timestamp stored directly in the _id of each document

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have the date field `createdAt` in your schema and you would like to get the number of users registered today, you should create a two date object instances to use in your date range query, `start` and `end` dates.

Your `start` date object should hold the current date time hours at `00:00:00.000` (milliseconds precision) and set the hours for today's date to `23:59:59.999` to the `end` date variable:

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);
```

Then pass the modified date objects as usual in your MongoDB aggregation pipeline in the **`$match`** operator:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "createdAt": { "$gte": start, "$lt": end }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
];

Model.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result){
    if (err) throw new Error();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

If you are using the [**momentjs**](http://momentjs.com/) library, this can be done by using the [**`startOf()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [**`endOf()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) methods on the moment's current date object, passing the string `'day'` as arguments:

```
var start = moment().startOf('day'); // set to 12:00 am today
var end = moment().endOf('day'); // set to 23:59 pm today
```